# Using a JSON REST Service in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to use a JSON REST Service inside my Silverlight Application so that I can display information from the REST service in my Silverlight App.  Below is my code but the ClientDownloadStringCompleted() is never stepped into and I'm not sure why.  The REST service does have data and is working.  I just can't seem to access it so I can parse out the data I need.  View of the JSON Service [image: JSON Service picture]

```
string jsonlink = "http://hou-prodserver2/ArcGIS/rest/services/sar/ScheduledRig/MapServer/81/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=MAXDATE%3E%271%2F1%2F1900%27&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=MAXDATE&f=pjson";

                var client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += ClientDownloadStringCompleted;
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(jsonlink, UriKind.Absolute));
```

*Below is Method I'm trying to use to get access to the data but it never gets used*

```
private void ClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //handle the response. 
        string result = e.Result;

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you get some Security Exception in your application?

Comment: Hi LB-  My application doesn't throw any exceptions that I can see.  Do you know how I can check for this?  I tried using a try, catch but it never enters the catch

Comment: put a breakpoint to line `string result = e.Result;` or watch your `output` window

Comment: @LB-  I've tried that but it never enters that method at all

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that service site has one or both of the following files at the root of the site:

- [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html)
- [clientaccesspolicy.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

If your Silverlight app is not on the same exact domain as the service, those files need to exist to allow it to connect. If they don't Silverlight fails silently.

Comment: Hi Jeff-  I have both of those files already in the wwwroot.  Would me debugging this application through Visual Studio somehow cause this security issue you are referring to?

Comment: Fiddler is a great tool to see what the server is returning to you so that you can see why your request is failing.

Comment: I second BPerreault, use Fiddler. You will see whether the crossdomain and clientaccesspolicy files are being returned, as well as possibly more information on why the request returns nothing.